# Finding C++ multimedia editing graph-like frameworks?

Tags: c++, frameworks, graph, editing, multimedia

I'm searching for multimedia editing graph-like frameworks where you can create graph elements with C++ and where you can build graphs for your app needs from elements of framework.

So far I know there are

- [GStreamer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GStreamer)
- [DirectShow](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectShow)
- [QuickTime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickTime)
- [Qt Phonon](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/phonon-overview.html) (cross-platform wrapper around first 3)

I wonder to see what else is out there - are there proprietary or open source, cross-platform or platform-dependent alternatives and what are their main goals?

Comment: FYI: Phonon is available sans Qt and has progressed quite a bit since Qt included it (Phonon is afaik on it's way out of Qt.).

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Media Foundation -- more or less a replacement for DirectShow. I don't see any drastic improvements, but if you want to use (for example) Microsoft's new H.264 decoder, you're pretty much stuck with it. As you can undoubtedly guess from the name, it's Windows only. Perhaps less obviously, it's supported only on Vista and later.

Another that sort of fits the description is [FFMpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/).

Comment: on FFmpeg - they just recently have started to have sort of filtering so probably it is an alternative... but FFmpeg is in C...

Comment: @Kabumbus: written in C, but still usable from C++.